# Stripe standalone :source => params[:stripeToken] error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-connect

I'm new to Stripe connect, building a marketplace app using stripe connect standalone, and require the user to enter a custom amount to pay the other user. The old form I was using worked fine, but once I changed to the new form, my :source  => params[:stripeToken] no longer generates, as well as :stripeEmail.  What is causing this?

> Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string

my original charges_controller.rb

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

def create
  # Amount in cents
  @amount = 500

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Wage Payment',
    :currency    => 'cad'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end
end
```

then I added the methods from the stripe recipe for custom amounts:

```
def create
   @amount = params[:amount]

  @amount = @amount.gsub('$', '').gsub(',', '')

  begin
    @amount = Float(@amount).round(2)
  rescue
    flash[:error] = 'Charge not completed. Please enter a valid amount in CAD ($).'
    redirect_to new_charge_path
    return
  end

  @amount = (@amount * 100).to_i # Must be an integer!

  if @amount < 500
    flash[:error] = 'Charge not completed. Payment amount must be at least $5.'
    redirect_to new_charge_path
    return
  end

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => @amount,
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :currency => 'cad',
    :source => params[:stripeToken],
    :description => ‘Payment'
  )

     customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end
```

I also modified the form, and added the javascript in charges/new.html.erb:

old form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_my_key');
</script>

<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="A month's subscription"
          data-amount="500"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

new form:

```
 <%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'form' do %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <article>
    <%= label_tag(:amount, 'Payment Amount:') %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:amount) %>
  </article>
  <article>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:stripeToken) %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:stripeEmail) %>
  </article>
  <button id='donateButton'>Pay Now</button>
<% end %>

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_CcUZ1IJxEqLR5RvVE3p5tx3U');
</script>
<script>


var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
  locale: 'auto',
  name: 'Payments',
  description: 'Wage',
  token: function(token) {
    $('input#stripeToken').val(token.id);
    $('input#stripeEmail').val(token.id);
    $('form').submit();
  }
});

    $('#donateButton').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $('#error_explanation').html('');

      var amount = $('input#amount').val();
      amount = amount.replace(/\$/g, '').replace(/\,/g, '')

      amount = parseFloat(amount);

      if (isNaN(amount)) {
        $('#error_explanation').html('<p>Please enter a valid amount in CAD ($).</p>');
      }
      else if (amount < 5.00) {
        $('#error_explanation').html('<p>Wage amount must be at least $5.</p>');
      }
      else {
        amount = amount * 100; // Needs to be an integer!
        handler.open({
          amount: Math.round(amount)
        })
      }
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      handler.close();
    });
    </script>
```

Now when I submit the custom amount, I am given the following error:

> You have passed a blank string for 'source'. You should remove the
>   'source' parameter from your request or supply a non-blank value
>
> Extracted source (around line #27):  Stripe::Charge.create(

Not sure how to proceed.  This error seems to be associated to creating charges, as the error is in the charges controller.  Or it is in the javascript of the new custom form.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please check params[:stripeToken] value, might be your stripe token not generating properly.

Comment: Did you check params[:stripeToken] value in your controller?

Comment: You are right, it is not being generated properly: "authenticity_token"=>"kdL18CbkOWWJMnytdU/IQx4WD+0IgfTzbLDEs1rV31O6dgLTV/MgA3HWfjBo5FgJ1mxrXxw9ZU8+BVO7LayxQg==", "amount"=>"10", "stripeToken"=>""}.  how do I fix this?

Comment: I've edited my form js from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049865/stripe-checkout-with-custom-integration-in-rails but am still having the same issue

Comment: Please create stripe.rb file inside config/initializers 

Rails.configuration.stripe = {
 :publishable_key =>  'PUBLISHABLE_KEY',  
 :secret_key =>  'SECRET_KEY'  
}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

Comment: Yes, I already had that..

Comment: Thanks for you help!  I was unable to determine the issue and have rolled back to basic  forms and charges to start over and try doing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the similar problem. But after few hours of struggle I figured it out. The reason is following. If you are using Rails 4.+ and using Turbolinks along with it, then it loads entire javascript for that page and when you are loading modal the javascript on that modal page wont work. You have to switch off the turbolink.

For me I switched off at the link level which is the link responsible for loading the charge/new page. Example:

   `<%= link_to "Buy", new_charge_path(product_id: @product.id),'data-no-turbolink' => true  %>`